# create file upload in joomla

Tags: ajax, joomla3.0

I want to create a module for uploading file in joomla with ajax .
I read a article in docs.joomla.org about the ajax in joomla .but that not useful for me.
how I can to create a modules for uploading file in joomla with ajax.